# Symfony: entity and sub-entity in a single form

Tags: forms, symfony

I have an entity, `studyInformation` which has a repetitive information for languages with *language + level + hasCertificate*. This is defined in 2 entities.

I define form type for both entities (using CRUD generator) and can  include language form type inside studyInformation form type (see form code).

But **my problem is**, `languageInformationType` has an entity field to select its `studyInformation`. I don't want this to be visible as for the user this association is invisible. When editing it's easy to hide the `languageInformationType` selector, but, how to handle it on new `studyInformation` form? how to *under the table* relate both entities? I guess I can do all work in controller by hand, getting all request parameters and instantiating and persisting entity *by hand*, but, is there a way to relay in tha magic of doctrine to do it? (`studyInformation` has MANY fields to process them *by hand*)

**ENTITIES**

```
/**
 * studyInformation
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class studyInformation
{
    /**
     * @var languageInformation
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="languageInformation", mappedBy="studyInformation", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="languages", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    private $languages;
```

And

```
/**
* languageInformation
*
* @ORM\Table()
* @ORM\Entity
*/
class languageInformation
{
    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="hasCertificate", type="boolean")
     */
    private $hasCertificate;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="level", type="integer")
     */
    private $level;

    /**
     * @var ListOfLanguages
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ListOfLanguages")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="languages", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    private $languages;

    /**
     * @var studyInformation
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="studyInformation", inversedBy="languages")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="studyInformation", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    private $studyInformation;
```

**FORM**

```
class studyInformationType extends AbstractType
{
     public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('languages', 'collection', array('type' => new languageInformationType()))
    ;
    }
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.  If you don't want user's to see the select element for studyInformation then don't add it to the form type.

Comment: Well, actually my doubt was, if I do that, then how to link studyInformation and languageInformation, but I think now I know how to do it: I will persist first studyInformation and then asign the id to languageInformation. Thanks

Comment: Actually, Doctrine 2 allows you to work at the object level.  No need to mess around with id's.  Just set the object references and let Doctrine take care of persisting.  It knows what to do.